# Can I delete the Docker folder in Library/Containers that takes up 64gb?

Tags: mac, storage

My Docker folder in `Library/Containers` takes up 64gb of space. Is it safe to delete this folder and reinstall Docker?

Answer (score 0):

Verify it actually is using 64GB. Docker reserves 64GB but it may not be using it.

You can find the VM Image here: `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/data/Docker.raw`

Locate it in Finder and open the Info window for it. Observe the size "on disk". You will see something like this:

`25,769,803,776 bytes (23.13 GB on disk)`

If it says `64,...,...,... bytes (X GB on disk)` then the `X` is the amount actually being used. The other amount isn't being used.

---

**You may delete this file, but you will lose all your Docker data**. This is where the Docker data is stored (images, containers, volumes).

If you don't want to do that, you can reduce the size by cleaning out old images/containers/volumes and reducing the allocated size in Docker Desktop Settings > Resources.

Comment: It looks like this file is specific to Docker *Desktop*. If one uses another implementation (e.g., Rancher Desktop) than it should be safe to delete it.